# Why does imagecrop remove the transparancy?

Tags: php, gd

When I load an image with a white background I can change the color white to transparant that results in a image with a transparant background. After this first step I want to crop the transparant image but then it will lose the transparancy.

After that I tried to crop the image first and make the cropped image his background transparant as I did before with the original image. With the original image it was working fine but the same method does not work for the cropped image.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Image resource
$image = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/html".$_GET["image"]);

// STEP 1 Make background transparant
$white = imagecolorexact($image, 255, 255, 255); 
imagecolortransparent($image, $white);  

// STEP 2 Crop the image
$image = imagecrop($image, ['x' => 15, 'y' => 49, 'width' => 382, 'height' => 382]);

// Serve the image
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Before the crop the image is transparant but uncropped, after the crop the image is resized but transparancy is lost. Switching the first and second step does not make any sense.

I also tried imagecopyresampled instead of imagecrop with the same results. Also switched the steps without any result.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Image resources
$image = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/html".$_GET["image"]);  
$new = imagecreatetruecolor(382, 382);

// STEP 1 Make background transparant
$white = imagecolorexact($image, 255, 255, 255); 
imagecolortransparent($image, $white);  

// STEP 2 Crop the image
imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 255, 255, 255, 127));
imagealphablending($new, false);
imagesavealpha($new, true);
imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 15, 49, 382, 382, 382, 382);

// Serve the image
imagepng($new);
imagedestroy($new);
```

Why does this not work the way I would expect?

Comment: why not make it transparent after cropping it?  Been a long time sense I manipulated images  5+ years.  But it seems like it might work ... lol

Comment: This happens when you mix palette based and true color images. Pay attention to the notes the manual has for imagecolortransparent in that regard, and also check out the user comments on that page.

Comment: Thank you, first comment in the manual is helping me, still not really understanding why this is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now.. I think the problem is the mix palette based and true color images like 04FS said.

```
function setTransparency($new_image,$image_source) {
  $transparencyIndex = imagecolortransparent($image_source); 
  $transparencyColor = array('red' => 255, 'green' => 255, 'blue' => 255); 

  if ($transparencyIndex >= 0) { 
    $transparencyColor = imagecolorsforindex($image_source, $transparencyIndex);    
  } 

  $transparencyIndex = imagecolorallocate($new_image, $transparencyColor['red'], $transparencyColor['green'], $transparencyColor['blue']); 
  imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $transparencyIndex); 
  imagecolortransparent($new_image, $transparencyIndex);
}

// Image resource
$image = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/html".$_GET["image"]); 
$imageNew = imagecreatetruecolor(382, 382);

setTransparency($imageNew, $image);

imagecopyresampled($imageNew, $image, 0, 0, 15, 49, 382, 382, 382, 382);

// Serve the image
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($imageNew);
imagedestroy($imageNew);
```